# React-google-maps warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started recently to learn React and I want to build a React App with Google Maps API so I downloaded React-google-maps package but its documentation is outdated. I have this sample code. Console logs error:

1. process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env
2. Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated
3. Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated.

TL:DR How to fix this code

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { 
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow, 
} from "react-google-maps";

const MapInit = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapLoad}
    defaultZoom={1}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
  >
  </GoogleMap>
));
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      markers: [
        {}
      ],
    };
    this.handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);
  }
  handleMapLoad(map) {
    this._mapComponent = map;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{height: `100%`}}>
        <MapInit
          containerElement={
            <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
          }
          mapElement={
            <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
          }
          onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MapContainer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are generated by the library which is probably not updated to use `class` instead of `createClass` and is importing PropTypes from React.

You can verify this by browsing to your node_modules and checking the source code. It's a little annoying but there's nothing you can do, apart from sending a pull request to fix it yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

> ### Versions
>
> - For `React >= 15.5`, use [next](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/releases/tag/v7.0.0)
>     tag on npm
> - For `React < 15.5`, use [latest](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/releases/tag/v6.3.0)
>     tag on npm

You need to update to v7.0.0 of react-google-maps to get rid of the deprecation warnings.

---

<strike>You might want to consider using [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) instead, which has more community activity and looks to be of higher quality.</strike>

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation of google-map-react? It's rather incomprehensible. Also I don't see how this has more community activity. Also, after some research it seems to me that the way marker are handled is quite different from the way google maps handles them. Which is probably difficult when you are coming from working with google maps java script api before.

Comment: @FabianBosler: I meant more that react-google-maps has a "Call for maintainers" because the original author isn't so interested in it at the moment. It's been a while since I looked, but I came away with the impression that google-map-react was of higher quality. They are for sure both usable.

Comment: Yea, certainly true. I browsed the page a bit and it looks like there a couple of maintainers who picked up the work, so I wouldn't be to worried about that personally.
Frankly, the documentation of both packages isn't great. But google-map-react is really subpar ...

Answer (score 0):

For second warning use https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types.

like
     `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

and for third use https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class